# Strimzi Kafka on GKE - org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine, strimzi

I've a Strimzi Kafka cluster on GKE, and i've a Spark structured streaming job which runs on Dataproc, picks up data from Kafka and does some processing.

It seems to be constantly giving the following Timeout 'warning' message :

```
22/06/22 19:40:49 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 26.0 (TID 243) (versa-structured-stream1-w-0.c.versa-sml-googl.internal executor 8): org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition syslog.ueba-us4.v1.versa.demo2-1 could be determined
```

I'm trying to understand why i'm getting this warning, and what needs to be done to fix this..  since this seems to be slowing down the processing

any inputs on this ?

tia!

Uploading the screenshot of the History Server:

[image: TimeOut Exception error in Kafka]

[image: error from History Server1]

[image]

Comment: Needs more details. Can the Spark executors reach the Kafka nodes? Is there authentication needed for your Kafka brokers?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - SSL is enabled for the Kafka nodes, also, how do i check if Spark Executors  can reach the Kafka nodes ? This seems to be intermittent, and is now resulting in failures sometimes

Comment: @OneCricketeer - i've uploaded screenshot of history server UI which shows the error

Comment: Can you share your Spark code and logs as text rather than images? Assuming you have a SSH access to the Spark executor machines, you test connectivity using tools like `netcat` or `telnet`